# How to disable post processor for some files with custom plugin in hexo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

I am using hexo and I want some files to only be processed by my custom processor. Though I have registered my custom processor and it does process some files(says A.md), the default post processor still processes and renders A.md. How to disable default processor for a file that has already been processed by another processor?

Comment: The default processor ignores all files that its name starts with `_` (underscore), so you can rename your files maybe with `__file` in order to be recognized by your own processor.